# IIS Express 64bit Request Timeout with .NET 4 & VS 2015

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, timeout, visual-studio-2015, iis-express

IIS Express 64bit, .NET4, MVC4, VS 2015.

I have a request that executes for up to 10 hours, however, IIS Express expires after one hour. (I am aware that holding an IIS instance for long time is not a good practice, however, this is acceptable in my situation).

> How can I change the request timeout of IIS Express?

I tried the following:

- Web.config adding `httpRuntime executionTimeout="someint"`
- ApplicationHost.config in the website directory I tried `webLimits`

Any suggestions are welcomed.